# IBM Watson Studio Kernel Error In Spark and Python Environment

Tags: python, apache-spark, ibm-watson, watson-studio

I am new to IBM Watson Studio and I am having issues in Spark and Python environments. I am getting "Could not find dataplane with the required capacity, please retry after sometime" error when I setup a notebook. I did try with other version of Spark and Python but I am getting the same error. Just Python environment works fine but Spark and Python causing problem. I did wait for 1 day as error said but Nothing is solved.

Thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved when I did change the region from Frankfurt to Dallas. There was some limitations by region as this [source](https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/docs/content/wsj/getting-started/known-issues.html) says.